# UnicodeEncode error in the process of inserting RSS data into the Mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, rss, feedparser

I am currently working on personal project that make news aggregator.
For that, i collected some sources about articles from some sites using Python `feedparser` lib. Following codes are functions of my module `digitaltrends.py`.

```
import feedparser
import requests
import re
import html

def cleanHtml(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr,'',raw_html)
    return cleantext

def to_utf(string):
    return string.encode('utf-8',errors='ignore').decode('utf-8')

def get_feed ():

    feed = 'https://www.digitaltrends.com/feed/'
    
    parsed_example = feedparser.parse (feed)
    press = to_utf(parsed_example['feed']['title'])
    articleList = []

    for items in parsed_example['entries'] :
        
        article = {}
        article['press'] = press
        article['link'] = to_utf(items.link)

        article['pubdate'] = to_utf(items.published)
        article['author'] =to_utf(items.authors[0]['name'])

        article['title'] = to_utf(items.title)
        article['summary'] = to_utf( html.unescape(cleanHtml(items.summary)) )

        
        if 'thumbnail' in items :
            article['thumbnail'] = to_utf(items['thumbnail'])

        else:
            article['thumbnail'] = None

        articleList.append(article)
    
    return articleList
```

After that , I created a table in my own DB by sending following query string :

```
# i made it roughly for my first test    
sql = '''CREATE TABLE articles (
            ID INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
            Press VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            Author VARCHAR(255),
            Pubdate TEXT NOT NULL,
            Summary TEXT,
            Link VARCHAR(3000) NOT NULL,
            Thumbnail VARCHAR(3000),
            PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    )'''
```

Finally, i tried to insert data into my table.

```
import digitaltrends
import MySQLdb as mysql
article_list = digitaltrends.get_feed()
''''' omitting connecting code '''''
sql = """INSERT INTO articles (Press,Title,Author,Pubdate,Summary,Link,Thumbnail) VALUES ("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")"""

for each_article in article_list:
    
    data = (each_article['press'],
            each_article['title'],
            each_article['author'],
            each_article['pubdate'],
            each_article['summary'],
            each_article['link'],
            each_article['thumbnail'])

    cursor.execute(sql,data)
    conn.commit()
```

And errors occurred during the execution of this code.

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-4d8567a1f7ad> in <module>()
     11             each_article['thumbnail'])
     12 
---> 13     cursor.execute(sql,data)
     14     conn.commit()
     15 #conn.rollback()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py in execute(self, query, args)
    232                 args = dict((key, db.literal(item)) for key, item in args.items())
    233             else:
--> 234                 args = tuple(map(db.literal, args))
    235             if not PY2 and isinstance(query, (bytes, bytearray)):
    236                 query = query.decode(db.encoding)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py in literal(self, o)
    316             s = self._tuple_literal(o)
    317         else:
--> 318             s = self.escape(o, self.encoders)
    319         # Python 3(~3.4) doesn't support % operation for bytes object.
    320         # We should decode it before using %.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py in unicode_literal(u, dummy)
    223             # unicode_literal() is called for arbitrary object.
    224             def unicode_literal(u, dummy=None):
--> 225                 return db.string_literal(str(u).encode(db.encoding))
    226 
    227         def bytes_literal(obj, dummy=None):

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2018' in position 18: ordinal not in range(256)
```

I have not set encoding to latin-1. My database and tables are also set to UTF-8 encoding. I tried to fix it myself, but i do not know why I get errors related to latin-1.

**Solved:**

My initial connection code :

```
conn = mysql.connect(host = 'localhost',
                        user = me,
                        password = pw,
                        db = bd,
                     )
```

After i added charset = 'utf8' parameter to connect function, it works well.

Comment: This error message seems to come from python, not mysql.

Comment: Try to use unicode: sql = u"""INSERT INTO articles...

Comment: please share your connection code which you have omitted